# Acess and modify a C++ vector containing objects with different variable types

Tags: c++, vector

Im just starting to learn C++ and i would like to acess and modify a vector of objects that have different variable types. I have only been able to create the vector, but cant do anything with it. How can i acess and modify it?
This is the code i have created so far:

```
class Person {
private: string name; int id;
public: 
    Person(string x, int y) { name = x; id = y; };
    ~Person(); 
};

int main()
{

vector<vector<Person>> v4;

}
```

Comment: A vector cannot contain different variable types.

Comment: So i would have to create a vector for each variable or perhabs create struct? -  @n.'pronouns'm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access objects stored in the vector you have different operators and methods such as `at()` or `operator[]` For more details check https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/

Since you want to learn C++, I assume you do not know what exactly to ask, so let me help you

Your code example lacks further things, besides accessing the objects in the vector:

- Since `name` and `id` are private you cannot access them.
- Your destructor has no implementation
- You created a vector of vectors of Persons. I assume you want just a vector.
- Your question regarding multiple types in one vector: This is not easily possible. Depending on what you want, you need multiple vectors, or need to combine your data (e.g. through `std::pair`, or you need to work with interfaces and inheritance.
- Your vector is empty

Let me construct something to give you a hint on where to continue:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Person {
private: 
    std::string name;
    int id;
public: 
    Person(std::string x, int y) { name = x; id = y; };
    // ~Person();  //This is not needed, since your class currently does not need any special handling during destruction

    // You need to be able to access name and id to be able to do something with them, for example print it
    std::string getName() const { 
        // be aware that this creates a copy of name. Thus changes to the returned string will not be reflected in the Person object.
        // Another option would be returning a reference (std::string&), but that I leave for you to research yourself
        return name;
    } 
    int getId() const {
        // same as for the name applies
        return id;
    }
    // This allows us to change the id of a Person
    void setId(int newId) {
        id = newId;
    } 
};

int main()
{
    // Lets create a Person first:
    Person p ("John", 1); // Please note that the string literal here will be used to construct an std::string on the fly and then store it in name of p

    // Create a second Person:
    Person p2 ("Jim", 2);

    // Create a vector and add the persons to it
    std::vector<Person> v;
    v.push_back(p);
    v.push_back(p2);

    // Print out the contents of the vector
    for (auto& pers : v) {
        std::cout << "Person " << pers.getName() << " has id " << pers.getId() << std::endl;
    }

    // Now change the id of the second person in the vector to 5 (note that indexes start at 0)
    v.at(1).setId(5);

    // Print again
    for (auto& pers : v) {
        std::cout << "Person " << pers.getName() << " has id " << pers.getId() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

To play around with it: https://godbolt.org/z/8dfEoa

I hope that helps you getting started.

Comment: TBH, i was aware of the set/get functions (but not the destructor implementation) and the fact that a single vector could contain different types. It is just that i couldnt acess/modify them and so i presented that vector of vectors potencial solution. But you are right, this really puts me on the right path. Thanks.

Comment: Btw. don't confuse objects and types. An object is an instantiation of a specific type, e.g. `Person` is the type while `p` and `p1` are objects of that type. A vector can hold many objects, but all have to have the same type.

Comment: BTW, can a vector of a class base hold an object of a derived class base?

Comment: Yes, this is possible. If you have `class Base` and `class Derived : public Base` you can make a `vector<Base>` and add objects of type `Base` and `Derived` to it. Please be aware that if you retrieve objects they will be of type `Base` so you only have the interface of `Base` available. If you want to work with something only available in `Derived` you can work with `dynamic_cast<Derived*>(...)` See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast for details